# Recommended books on Web Services and Portlets

Tags: java, web-services, soa, portlet

Our manager today has informed us that our group will now handle a new project for which we are not so familiar. He only got a brief overview also of the details.

According to him, this is a project that uses Portlets that calls web services call and implements SOA architecture. I see three topics here for which I am not familiar.

- Portlets
- Web Services
- SOA

I learn fast by reading books but when I looked up at Amazon to purchase a book, I saw a lot of books on web services. I cannot filter which book would suit my needs as I see lots of topic (RESTful Web Service/SOA/Web Service...).

Portlets book is another of my problem also. I have checked also other questions on SO but I am not sure if they are the same with my problem so I decided to post to clearly state my question.

By far I have  experience only using Servlets/JSP/Struts/Spring but this does not stop me from signing up for the job since I think this would be a good opportunity for learning.

Comment: I dont know about Portlets, but for SOA, you should try to understand a technology or language-agnostic concepts of it. Its a way of solving problems or building software, I'd highly recomment [Thomas Erl's book](http://www.amazon.com/SOA-Principles-Service-Design-Thomas/dp/0132344823).

Comment: Sorry this might be dumb but, do I need to learn web services before I pick up that book? Thanks

Comment: If you already have professional programming experience for a while you'd get it pretty fast, webservices are nothing hard or complex to comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[J2EE Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146182) is a good read on Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

[Portlets In Action](http://manning.com/sarin/) is a good book on portlets. Leans towards Liferay for the examples but still vendor neutral.